# Looping Over Categories to Create Individual Regressions

Tags: r, economics

In addendum to my previous question, I want to then create a for loop, each iteration of which would create a regression for each unique code I have created. More specifically, I want to create a regression with only the data that correspond to each unique code. How do I do this?

I have tried Googling "for loops in R" and have failed to find an answer that suits my need to iterate over categories rather than variables.

Comment: You need to provide a reproducible example including sample data, yours or reference to one available on R (`data()` for examples from package `datasets` which is automatically loaded when you start R). Probably you do not want a loop, but the `lapply()` function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example predicting Sepal.Length from Sepal.Width, Petal.Length, and Petal.Width for each of three species using the `iris` data:

```
data(iris)
str(iris)
# 'data.frame': 150 obs. of  5 variables:
#  $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
#  $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
#  $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
#  $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
#  $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Now `split` and `lapply`:

```
iris.split <- split(iris[, -5], iris$Species)
iris.lm <- lapply(iris.split, \(x) lm(Sepal.Length~Sepal.Width+Petal.Length+Petal.Width, x))
lapply(iris.lm, summary)
```

The last line prints summary reports for the regressions for each species.